# Properly handling initialization in generic methods

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, software-design

Suppose I have an object of some type A and want to transform it into type B. Let's say multiple implementations of this interface will exist as we will have many children of A, and B. So, I create an interface like:

```
interface IAToB {
    B Transform<A, B>(A a);
}
```

The problem with this interface that I see is I need to initialize an object of type B in Transform, which means if I change the initialization logic of B, I need to appropriately change all implementations of IAToB. So, consider the following:

```
interface IAToB {
    void Transform<A, B>(A a, out B b);
}
```

The implementer of IAToB is now required to pass in an initialized B.

So, is the latter interface more compliant with SOLID principles in comparison to the former? Or am I just moving the coupling around without actually reducing it, so to speak? Further, would it make sense to place the generics in the definition of the interface too, to have `interface IAToB<A, B> { ... }`?

Comment: `The implementer of IAToB is now required to pass in an initialized B.`  This statement is incorrect.  They are required to pass in an `out` parameter, which can be un-initialized.  In fact, any previous value held by that parameter will be ignored, and isn't relevant.

Comment: Oh right that makes sense. Ultimately, I believe I want to decouple the initialization process from the Transform method, so if I remove the ```out``` keyword, this would then force the implementation to handle initialization of B? Or is this the wrong way to think about it?

Comment: But if the calling code needs to provide an initialized instance, then wouldn't this just "move the problem"? (i.e. in the case that you need to _"change the initialization logic of B"_ you would then still have to change every code that creates a new B). If you just want to _"decouple the initialization"_, then have you considered creating a separate factory class / method for creating new instances?

Comment: Right, that's why I was asking which approach is more appropriate due exactly to that kind of issue. I'm confused as to the best way to implement this sort of type transformer. At some point type B needs to be initialized in order to start putting data into to it based off of the data in type A, so where is the best place to put the initialization?

Comment: Interfaces shouldn't care about implementation details.  You're overthinking this.  If you wanted you could add a parameter for a factory to produce B.  Then callers could pass in that factory and implementors of this interface won't have to care.  But I don't think that's a good option; this should be left up to implementations.

Comment: Your interface is a contract which says "if you give me an A, I will give you a B in response which is some kind of transformation of A".  Note that the contract does not specify how, *specifically*, B was created.

Comment: That makes more sense now. So with a factory, I could stick to implementing the first interface and pass in a factory so I can initialize a type B object without having to pass in any sort of object to the Transform method?

Comment: If you want to make it part of the contract, yes, you can formalize it that way.  I guess.  I don't think it should be, but I don't know your problem domain, and we're moving into opinion territory.

Answer (score 1):

> *"The implementer of IAToB is now required to pass in an initialized B. So, is the latter interface more compliant with SOLID principles in comparison to the former"*

The first statement here isn't true. An `out` parameter is guaranteed to be initialized by the called method, and it is not required that it's pre-initialized to anything (doing so, in fact, is redundant and should be avoided). It's only a reference that the caller can access after the method completes. Therefore the answer is, "No, it's not any more SOLID than the first example."

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier):

> Variables passed as out arguments do not have to be initialized before being passed in a method call. However, the called method is required to assign a value before the method returns.

Typically an `out` parameter is used so that a method can return more than one result. `TryParse` is a typical example, in that it returns a `bool` indicating success, and sets an `out` parameter to the parsed value (or the default for the type if it's not successful).

---

Furthermore, no matter how you implement this conversion method, if you change the initiliaztion logic in a way that impacts how a `B` can be created from an `A`, then you're going to have to update the conversion code *somewhere*.

Comment: Thank you, that answered my question. So, how should I approach the initialization? What's the best way to think about this kind of thing? Would a factory make sense, as others have commented? The thing is right now, a parameterless constructor is all I need for children of type A and B, so I'm not sure if I'm over thinking this completely. It's unlikely that I will need to change the initialization logic but I also don't like introducing coupling in case I do need to change something.

Comment: The initialization of B has *nothing* to do with your interface.  That is up to individual implementations.  If you want to *force* it part of the interface, you can, but like I said in my comments under the question, I don't think you should.

Comment: Thank you Amy. I didn't think I was conflating the abstraction and implementation before, but as you had mentioned, I was, which lead to my confusion. Your previous comments are making even more sense now.

Comment: Yeah, there is no coupling involved here, since this is just an interface. Any breaking changes made will need to be handled by the implementations of the interface, but not the interface itself. Also, it sounds like you're worried about something that will likely not happen. As long as the current design is solid, I wouldn't spend too much time developing an elaborate system in an effort to "future-proof" the code.